# Getting "The document was created using an evaluation version of activereports"

Tags: activereports

I am using ActiveReports6 for my windows forms application
When I install it on my machine providing serial key it works perfectly fine.
But when I don't install it, it shows this red line in the bottom of the report

```
The document was created using an evaluation version of activereports..
```

My understanding may not be correct, but what I tried is I installed licensed version of ActiveReports6 to my computer and then copied all the dlls generated for ActiveReports6 from GAC and added them to my project thinking now they will work on any machine as they are generated by licensed version of the software.

And then uninstalled Activereports6, but when I tried it still gave me the same evaluation version message.

So is it mandatory that active reports has to be installed in all the machines where I deploy my client? Or I did something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake I was doing.

Actually I had put licenses.licx file in the subdirectory of the project while it should be in the same directory of the project and so I was not generating its exe.licenses file and so did not work.

Once I changed the location of licx file it worked! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The license for development.   You would install activereports, create your reports and build your application on the licensed machine, the VS compiler will automatically check the licensed components and include the license within your application.   You do not need to install ActiveReports itself on your client, only make sure that you are deploying the ActiveReports assemblies with your application.   if you are having any issues please contact us at http://activereports.grapecity.com and we would gladly resolve the issue for you.

Comment: you need to make sure that ActiveReports assemblies are referenced in your project.

Comment: They are referenced and that's why project is building and running but, I am getting this message at the bottom of the reports.

Comment: check for licenses.licx.  Make sure you have one in the project and that it is included in the project. see "Required references in the licenses.licx file (for Standard and Professional Editions)" section @ http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/Legacy/ActiveReports6/topic34.html

Comment: Also, if this exe/dll is not the calling executable, the calling exe will also need to be updated with licx/references (whether it contains actvereports reports or not) and compiled.  If you are still having issues, please email activereports.support@grapecity.com with ref to this post.